# How to remove Newline while printing string

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

```
.data
.align 2
array:  .space  80
size:   .word   20
string: .space  20000
arrayLength:    .asciiz "Enter the array length : "
input:  .asciiz "Enter string : "
result: .asciiz "\nString Array = { "
cls:    .asciiz "}"
space:  .asciiz " "

.text 
main:
    li  $v0,4
    la  $a0,arrayLength
    syscall
    
    li  $v0, 5
    syscall
    addi    $s0,$v0,0
    
    add $t0,$zero,$zero
    addi    $t1,$zero,1
    la  $s2,string

read_String:
    bgt $t1,$s0,L1
    
    li  $v0,4
    la  $a0,input
    syscall
    
    move    $a0,$s2
    li  $a1,20
    li  $v0,8
    syscall
    
    sw  $a0,array($t0)
    
    addi    $t0,$t0,4
    addi    $t1,$t1,1
    addi    $s2,$s2,20
    
    j   read_String

L1:
    add     $t0,$zero,$zero     
        addi    $t1,$zero,1         

        la      $a0,result
        li      $v0,4
        syscall
        
while:
        bgt     $t1,$s0,done        
        lw      $t2,array($t0)      

        li      $v0,4
        move    $a0,$t2
        syscall

        addi    $t0,$t0,4         
        addi    $t1,$t1,1          
        j       while

done:
    li  $v0,4
    la  $a0,cls
    syscall

        li      $v0,10
        syscall
```

Comment: I want to print like this String Array = { string int char }

Comment: but each string is prints in newline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MARS & QTSPIM syscall #8 read a string, but that includes the new line the user uses to end the string input.  This syscall also appends a NUL character, '\0', to make the entered string a C-style null terminated string.

If you don't want the newline that is captured when the user enters the string, you have to remove it yourself.  The easiest thing to do is to overwrite the '\n' character in the entered string with a NUL, removing the new line and shortening the string by 1.

Since, the syscall #8 does not return a length (from which you could go back 1 to locate the new line character), you have to locate the newline by searching for it, byte by byte.  When you find it overwrite it with a 0 to terminate the string there.